# PrimeNG new Chart Release in R.C.1

Tags: charts, primeng

I have update my primeNG to version to RC.1.
While doing so, I have made all the necessary changes required to run the application. Its been running fine.
Problem is that in this updated version, the Chart implementation has been changed.
Rather than using  we have to use 
After doing this change, I am not getting the component rendered on my browser. It is not giving any error in the console.

following is my code:
app.component.ts File:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {InputText,DataTable,Button,Dialog,Column,Header,Footer} from 'primeng/primeng';

export class AppComponent {
data :any;
constructor(private carService: CarService) {

this.data = {
labels: ['A','B','C'],
datasets: [
{
data: [300, 50, 100],
backgroundColor: [
"#FF6384",
"#36A2EB",
"#FFCE56"
],
hoverBackgroundColor: [
    "#FF6384",
    "#36A2EB",
    "#FFCE56"
]
}] 
};
}
}
```

app.conponent.html:

```
<div>
    <p-chart type="pie" [data]="data"></p-chart>
</div>
```

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.